# Ember singletons - implementing current_user behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, authentication, ember.js, devise

I'm working on a rails 4, ember-rails, ember-source 1.2.0 application, with devise for authentication.

I have the app successfully issuing authentication requests, receiving the user details, and now I need a good place to store "current_user" throughout the app. I've tried writing my own initializer to do some injection but it doesn't seem to be a well documented code path:

```
Admin.initializer({
  name: 'currentUser',
  initialize: function(container, application){
    container.optionsForType('user', { instantiate: false, singleton: true });

    application.register('user:current',Admin.User.createRecord({}));
    application.inject('route','current_user','user:current')
    application.inject('controller','current_user','user:current')
    application.inject('view','current_user','user:current')
  }
})
```

This code errors because:

```
Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
```

How can I register a single model and make it visible all the way to the view level? Once I have the singleton registered I will issue an ajax login request and fill in its properties or send the user to a login screen.

Comment: I would set the current_user model to the controller, then use that as the point to share across the application layers. Controllers can depend on one another by setting them within the `needs` array, and you can access the controllers from the view with `this.get('controller.controllers.current_user')`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works, your error is happening somewhere else.  You'll need to show additional information.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/esEYIrIR/2/edit